# How to change background in ggrepel in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, ggrepel

I have trouble with datavisualisation.

My code looks like this:

```
t <- structure(list(occurrences_article = c(4, 11, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 2, 4, 4, 11, 3, 6, 10, 2, 1, 2),
                    score = c(2, 1.76, 0.9, 1.875, 1.93, 1.92, 1.42, 1.5, 1.6, 1.75, 1.29, 1.5, 2, 1.65, 2, 2, 2
                    ), 
                    Barrier_code = c("information", "beliefs", "trust", "lack_traditional_motivations", "perceived_quality", "proximity", "shortage", "access_criteria", "functioning", "perceived_accessibility", "fees", "perceived_affordability", "lack_of_subsidies", "cultural_ressources", "social_ressources", 
                                     "sustainability", "satisfaction"), 
                    Quality_coded = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L
                    ), .Label = c("Low", "Medium", "High"), class = "factor"), treatable_behavioral_intervention = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
library(RColorBrewer)

t$Barrier_code <- as.factor(t$Barrier_code)
t$score <- as.numeric(t$score)
t$Quality <- as.numeric(t$Quality)
t$Quality_coded <- as.factor(t$Quality_coded)

ggplot(t, aes(occurrences_article, score, label = Barrier_code, colour = Quality_coded))+
  geom_point(size =2)+
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = Barrier_code, fill = levels(t$treatable_behavioral_intervention), color = "black"))+ 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn")
```

But the produced graph is unsatisfying [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBjlm.png)

The thing is I would like to change the background of the label with two different color, depending on the two levels of `treatable_behavioral_intervention` (failed attempt with `+ scale_fill_manual(values = setNames(c("lightblue","darkgreen"), levels(t$treatable_behavioral_intervention)))`, also in order to make yellow labels readable..
Could-you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's more a typo- you were very much on the right track. Your code doesn't run as posted (there is a large gap in your data, but that's fine).

Avoid `$` in aes, and I am not quite sure why you're using `levels`...

Don't!  Just use `as.factor(variable)`. Or also possible `as.character`.

```r
library(ggrepel)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

t <- structure(list(occurrences_article = c(4, 11, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 2, 4, 4, 11, 3, 6, 10, 2, 1, 2),
                    score = c(2, 1.76, 0.9, 1.875, 1.93, 1.92, 1.42, 1.5, 1.6, 1.75, 1.29, 1.5, 2, 1.65, 2, 2, 2
                    ), 
                    Barrier_code = c("information", "beliefs", "trust", "lack_traditional_motivations", "perceived_quality", "proximity", "shortage", "access_criteria", "functioning", "perceived_accessibility", "fees", "perceived_affordability", "lack_of_subsidies", "cultural_ressources", "social_ressources", 
                                     "sustainability", "satisfaction"), 
                    Quality_coded = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L
                    ), .Label = c("Low", "Medium", "High"), class = "factor"), treatable_behavioral_intervention = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


t$Barrier_code <- as.factor(t$Barrier_code)
t$score <- as.numeric(t$score)
t$Quality_coded <- as.factor(t$Quality_coded)

ggplot(t, aes(occurrences_article, score, label = Barrier_code, colour = Quality_coded))+
  geom_point(size =2)+
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = Barrier_code, 
                       fill = as.factor(treatable_behavioral_intervention)# that's the trick
                       ), # changed bracket
                       color = "black")+ 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn") +
  scale_fill_brewer()
```

[image]

Or, manually define the colors:

```
ggplot(t, aes(occurrences_article, score, label = Barrier_code, colour = Quality_coded))+
  geom_point(size =2)+
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = Barrier_code, 
                       fill = as.factor(treatable_behavioral_intervention)# that's the trick
  ), # changed bracket
  color = "black")+ 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Red", "Yellow", "Green")) +
  scale_fill_brewer()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much, it helps a lot, I guess I got mixed up in my code, then thought I did something completely wrong... However, I would like "high", "medium" and "low" dots to be colored respectively in "green", "yellow" and "orange' (or red, I don't mind). I don't understand why there is a "black" level in red that is displayed with these labels. I mean, it tried to specified `color = "black"`so that the yellow labels became readable but...

Comment: @LaudineCarbuccia happens to the best of us.  no worries at all

Comment: One more thing (so sorry):  I would like "high", "medium" and "low" dots to be colored respectively in "green", "yellow" and "orange' (or red, I don't mind). I don't understand why there is a "black" level in red that is displayed with these labels. I mean, it tried to specified `color = "black"`so that the yellow labels became readable but...

Comment: @LaudineCarbuccia not sure I understand. In my graph, the dots are colored ... ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely ! But I would like to color them in "green", "orange" and "red', like traffic lights, for "High", "Medium" and "Low" (there are referring to quality). I initially went for ` "RdYlGn"` palette because it was the best way I found, but dots are not of the right colors.. :(

Comment: (my graph is pretty heavy so I would like to make it as intuitive as possible)

Comment: Ah. I see. Wait a sec.

Comment: I tried that, but for orange label with the darkest blue fill, it is still not very readable
`
ggplot(t, aes(occurrences_article, score, label = Barrier_code, colour = Quality_coded))+
  geom_point(size =2)+
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = Barrier_code, 
                       fill = as.factor(treatable_behavioral_intervention)))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#D55E00", "#E69F00", "#009E73"))+
  scale_fill_brewer()
`

Comment: @LaudineCarbuccia you need to remove color = black from aes. using brewer RdYlGn works actually. see updated code